# TSQL SELECT based on a condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, conditional-statements

I am trying to do a select from CTE based on a condition.

There is a variable I've declared for today's period (`@PRD`). It holds the value of what period we are currently in.

Now I would like to do a selection from a table that will restrict what information is returned based on whether we are in the first half of the year or not.

For instance, we are in period 2 so I want everything returned from my CTE which falls between PRD 1 and 5. IF we were in say period 6  (after 5), then yes I'd want everything returned from the table.

This is the pseudocode of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN @PRD <= 5
         THEN (SELECT * FROM DISPLAY WHERE PERIOD IN (1,2,3,4,5))
         ELSE (SELECT * FROM DISPLAY)
    END
```

I'm getting an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Please any thoughts on how I can do this?

Thanks x

EDITED/UPDATED:

More of the code involves a CTE and is really long. Bottom line is lets say I have this CTE

```
;WITH DISPLAY as (
     select * from lots_of_things
)
SELECT * FROM DISPLAY
```

Having done a regular select on this CTE, it returns data that looks like this:

```
PERIOD (INT)    DEPARTMENT   GROUP  BUDGET
1               ENERGY       HE     500
2               ENERGY       HE     780
3               ENERGY       HE     1500
4               ENERGY       HE     4500
5               ENERGY       HE     400
6               ENERGY       HE     3500
7               ENERGY       HE     940
8               ENERGY       HE     1200
```

I want it to show me just the top 5 rows if we the current period is 1,2,3,4,5. But to display ALL table rows if we are in any other period like 6,7,8,9 and onwards. The current period is held in the variable @PRD which is derived from doing a comparison of today's date with ranges held in a table. The value is accurate and also type INT

Hope this helps

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff89f/6)

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* that returns a *single* value (per row). Can you not show more of your current code - that generates the error message you're showing?

Comment: How many "periods" are there and how do they relate to the calendar year? Your logic seems strange: "we are in period 2 so I want everything returned from my CTE which falls between PRD 1 and 5" !? but I suppose if that's what you need...

Comment: Hi Damien. That was the code that generates the error in it's entirety. It was at the tail end of a cte...will update to show this

Comment: Hi Tony. The only bit I have issue with is the bit that displays the rows. Not with my CTE or how my @PRD is derived. My logic is fine. It's a requirement in the department and I just need to do it not question it lol But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Chen - Fair enough, if that's what they want, but it's always good to question requirements :)

Comment: In this case I understand why, just didnt think it was essential to explain that when that isn't the issue here

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I've updated the question with a bit more info and a link to fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT * FROM DISPLAY WHERE (@PRD > 5 OR PERIOD IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

If this code confuses you, what's happening is that we check if @PRD > 5 and if that returns true, our expression is always true so we return all the rows.
If the variable is less or equal to 5 (like you checked in your example), the first check is false and then we check if the period is the list.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Duh! Been staring at it for hours and the most obvious of solutionsss omg...THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU xxxx

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution:

```
IF @PRD <= 5
  SELECT * FROM DISPLAY WHERE PERIOD IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM DISPLAY
```

**UPD**

In this case you should use variable instead of CTE, if it's possible.

```
DECLARE @PRD INT;
SELECT @PRD = PERIOD FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ...
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. I'm on SQL 2008 BTW. And also this follows a CTE (if that has any bearing).

Comment: @Chen, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f824/1 - should work. Can you provide more details? What were the lines before `IF`?

Comment: Hi Smileek. I dont see an output :S Is that the right sqlfiddle link?

Comment: @Chen, I didn't put any data, so it just checks the query. You can add some `INSERT`s in the left pane, if it's necessary.

Comment: @Smileek unfortunately your code will not work in his situation. He uses CTE and that's why he's getting the incorrect syntax at "IF".

Comment: Hiya...it doesn't work. I think perhaps it's because it's a CTE? I'm not sure but it doesnt work. Did you test it perhaps?

Comment: @Chen, yep, I did, but with variable, not with CTE. Please, check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Smileek. It's a small part of a very big series of queries all within CTEs. It'd be hard to dump the CTE if the IF statements don't play nice with them. Thankfully there is a solution but thanks for your help. Least now I know to use IF statements next time :)